# A question about group ring of a group over matrix ring!

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, group-rings

Let $S$ be a ring and $G$ a group.
 We denote by $SG$ the group ring of $G$ over $S$. Let $S=M_n(R)$ be the set of all $n \times n$ matrices over a ring $R$. Is it true $SG\cong M_n(RG)$ (as rings)?

Thanks to anybody answering!

Comment: How do you define group rings over noncommutative rings? By the same formula as for commutative ones?

Comment: @darij grinberg Please see the following book, Ch. 3: An introduction to group rings, C. P. Milies and S. K. Sehgal or following link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_ring#Definition

Comment: Okay. So let's look at the map $SG \to M_n\left(RG\right)$ that sends any $\sum_{g \in G} \left(a_{g,i,j}\right)_{1\leq i\leq n,\ 1\leq j\leq n} \left[g\right] \in SG$ (where $\left[g\right]$ stands for the standard basis element corresponding to $g \in G$ in the group ring of $G$) to $\left(\sum_{g \in G} a_{g,i,j} \left[g\right]\right)_{1\leq i\leq n,\ 1\leq j\leq n} \in M_n\left(RG\right)$. This map is clearly bijective. Is it a ring homomorphism? I think it is, for simple reasons (keep in mind that the definition of $SG$ yields ...

Comment: ... that $\left(a\left[g\right]\right)\left(b\left[h\right]\right) = ab\left[gh\right]$ for any $a, b \in S$ and $g, h \in G$). Make sure to actually do the computation :)

Comment: Dear dr.  Grinberg, that's exactly the point! Does this natural map work as a ring isomorphism? It is difficult for me and i dont know that my computation is right! It's boring! I want to know if anyone else faced this issue? I think that this isomorphism is correct, but I have no reason!

Comment: Thank you for your useful comment, dr. Grinberg

Answer (score 0):

We have $M_n(R) G \cong M_n(RG)$ as rings. Indeed, define the map $$\psi: M_n(R)G \to M_n(RG): \sum_{g \in G} A^g g \mapsto \left(\sum_{g \in G} A_{ij}^g g\right)_{1\leq i,j \leq n}$$

Clearly this is well-defined. This is a ring morphism:

$$\psi\left(\sum_g A^g g + \sum_g B^g g\right) = \psi\left(\sum_g (A^g +B^g)g \right)$$
$$= \left(\sum_{g \in G}((A^g + B^g)_{ij}g\right)_{ij} $$
$$= \left(\sum_{g \in G}(A_{ij}^g + B_{ij}^g)g\right)_{ij}$$

$$= \left(\sum_{g \in G}A_{ij}^g +\sum_{g \in G} B_{ij}^gg\right)_{ij}$$
$$= \left(\sum_{g \in G}A_{ij}^g\right)_{ij} +\left(\sum_{g \in G} B_{ij}^gg\right)_{ij}$$
$$=\psi\left(\sum_g A^g g\right) + \psi\left(\sum_g B^g g\right)$$

and

$$\psi\left(\left(\sum_g A^g g \right) \left( \sum_h B^h h\right)\right)$$
$$= \psi\left(\left(\sum_g A^g g \right) \left( \sum_h B^h h\right)\right)$$

$$= \psi\left(\sum_{g,h} A^g B^h (gh)\right)$$
$$=  \left(\sum_{g,h} (A^g B^h)_{ij} gh\right)_{ij}$$

$$=\left(\sum_{g,h} \sum_{k=1}^n (A^g_{ik} B^h_{kj}) gh\right)_{ij}$$

On the other hand,

$$\left(\psi\left(\sum_{g} A_g g\right) \psi\left(\sum_{h} B_h h\right)\right)_{ij}$$

$$= \left(\sum_{k=1}^n \left(\sum_{g} A_{ik}^g g\right)\left(\sum_h B_{kj}^h h\right)\right)_{ij}$$

$$= \left(\sum_{k=1}^n \sum_{g,h} A_{ik}^g B_{kj}^h (gh)\right)_{ij}$$

and $\psi$ preserves multiplication because we can interchange the last two sums.

Surjectivity is clear and injectivity should also be clear. You can also check that if $R$ has an identity, that $\psi$ preserves the identity.

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: If it helped, you can accept  the answer :)